# Text matches in debugger, but no results returned

Tags: search, solr

I've got an issue where my index and query are exactly the same, however no results are returned. It seems to fail on any words that are longer than the ENGTF max length. Here's my schema.

```
<fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />

    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" preserveOriginal="1" types="wdfftypes.txt" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" words="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="10" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
   <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" words="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Here is a screenshot of the analyzer when "Satisfaction" is put into the index, and "Satisfaction" is put into the query.

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once obvious option is to increase the nGram length limit. You seem to be aware of this option and probably agree that is is not ideal.

Another option is to create a second field to use the nGram search, and another to use a search without nGram. For exmaple, somewhere in your `schema.xml` you might see:

```
<field name="myCoolNGramField" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<!-- make a new type, text_en_non_ngram, and use it for this new field below. -->
<field name="myCoolField" type="text_en_non_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<copyField source="myCoolNGramField" dest="myCoolField" />
```

Comment: Exactly, that was sort of my last resort fix. I was trying to avoid that since it's a workaround that most definitely shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: It is not really a huge workaround. It is quite a common technique to use when you wish to treat the input in two different ways. For someone who just wanted a simple n-gram filter, they may be slightly frustrated if it started matching whole tokens as you wish.